# PCRE regex with multiples substrings

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to get 2 substrings from this line :

> open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

In the first I must have `/etc/ld.so.cache` and in the second `/etc/ld.so.cache`.

So I wrote this

```
int main()
{

    char * line = "open(\"/etc/ld.so.cache\", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3";

    int         rc;
    size_t      nmatch = 3;

    regex_t     reg;
    regmatch_t  pmatch[3];

    char * regex = "open\(\"\\([^\"]*\\)\",[ ]\\([^\)]*\\)\).*";

    rc = regcomp(&reg, regex, REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED);

    rc = regexec(&reg, line, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
    if (!rc) {
            printf("Matched substring \"%.*s\" is found at position %d to %d.\n",
                     pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &line[pmatch[1].rm_so],
                     pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - 1);

    }

    regfree(&reg);

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't return the first group.

Could you tell me, if my regex is good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly. In POSIX regexes, parentheses and other special characters have to be escaped if you want them to match themselves, not to access their special function, so it has to be

```
char const * regex = "open\\(\"([^\"]*)\", *([^\\)]*)\\).*";
```

In addition, if you want the captures, you have to compile the regex without `REG_NOSUB`:

```
rc = regcomp(&reg, regex, REG_EXTENDED);
```

...and the `printf` will probably segfault on you at the moment; the arguments don't match the format string.